# What does it determine the placedItem.width and placedItem.height , when adding one without specifying those properties?

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm in `Adobe Illustrator 2022 26.064` and I'm placing an item. It is the thirdone I place in the same document.

```
var placedItem3 = doc.placedItems.add();
placedItem3.file = new File("/c/files/dotfiles-win/illustrator-scripts/lorem-picsum/3to2-1080x720.jpg");
placedItem3.name = "placedItem3";
```

For some reason it gets `placedItem.width=3061,41` ,`placedItem.height=2040,94`
When the file is `1080x720`
The previous items were placed keeping the same dimensions of the file.

Comment: Looks like the jpg files have different dpi (ppi). Could you check their resolutions (dpi, ppi) in Photoshop?

Comment: 3to1 has 25 dpi while the others have 72 dpi , this is the whole code https://hastebin.com/ziraqeluse

Comment: 2040.94 / 28,346 = 72 ...hmm. I think at some point pixels per inch (72) became pixels per cm (28,346) or viceversa. I'm sure the problem is in the jpg files. I see no problem in the code. Try to resave them with Photoshop with 72 dpi and see.

Comment: It seems to be there the issue , so If I try to resize it with Photoshop , after I do the > Image Size > Resampling ... , When I'm about to export it , it will change the Width to 3061 and Height to 2041.  So understanding I can do it manually with Photoshop, I need a way to determine the dimensions that app.activeDocument.placedItem will take.

Comment: I'm not quite understand. If you still need help? Illustrator places images as is with their native size. You can change the size after if it's need. You can get or calculate a resolution of any placed image any time, and change the size based on this info, etc. I mean with a script, of course. Let me know if you need help

Comment: Ok , so to deterministicaly determine the Height and Width of a placedItem , I shall not check the metadata of the image as such, but make a certain calculation with the following values.  `Image Width` and `X resolution` , `Image Height` and `Y resolution` . Illustrator is not using `Image Width` only but it is applying a coefficient to it `X resolution` . Do you know the exact formula? Thanks

Comment: I need to see a deterministic criteria to do this. How does `Adobe Illustrator` tell about the ppi of the image? . Comparing the metadata with `exiftool` of the original image downloaded from internet and the one modified with photoshop I get https://hastebin.com/wofazikelo , which basically shows the incosistency of the metadata across the pics. The original has `Image WIdth` and `X Resolution` while the Secondone lacks of `X Resolution` , how does Illustrator tell of the Secondone `ppi` ? Does it handle any sort of metadata `exiftool` is not aware of ?

Comment: I've added the example how you can find out ppi of raster images.

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out ppi of a `image` with the formula:

```
72 / image.matrix.mValueA
```

For example here is the script that finds images with ppi less than 250 and selects them:

```
var min = 250; // target ppi
var rasters = app.activeDocument.rasterItems;
var i = rasters.length;
while (i--) if (72/rasters[i].matrix.mValueA < min) rasters[i].selected = true;
```

Illustrator does it in a rather uncommon way via the transformation matrix

- [Matrix](https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/Matrix.html)

I'm not sure if there are another ways as well. And probably it might require additional steps for rotated images.